# How can I observe whether a fragment manager currently has an animation running?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, `CatFragment` and `DogFragment`. I got a new dog and don't love my cat anymore, so I want to add `DogFragment()` on top of `CatFragment`, and do a crossfade animation between them.

```
fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out,
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out
                )
                .add(R.id.frame, DogFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .hide(fragmentManager!!.findFragmentByTag(CatFragment.TAG))
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

My `CatFragment()` has two states:

1. `Cat` (a beautiful picture of my cat)
2. `LoadingABetterPet` (just a progress bar)

Internally the fragment's views crossfade when switching between these states.

My `DogFragment()` has 1 state: a beautiful picture of my brand new dog.

### Flow:

The user sees the following flow:

`CatFragment.Cat` --(internal crossfade)-> `CatFragment.LoadingABetterPet` --
 (fragment manager crossfade)--> `DogFragment`.

When the user hits back while `DogFragment` is visible, I want them to see `CatFragment` in its `Cat` state.

However, while `DogFragment` is animating onto the screen, `CatFragment` in parallel internally runs its own crossfade animation from `LoadingABetterPet` to `Cat`. This causes some artifacting during the `.add()` fragment manager animation where the user partially sees my cat.

To avoid this, I would like `CatFragment` to delay animating from `LoadingABetterPet` back to `Cat` while `fragmentManager` is running animations. How can I do this?

Does the support fragment manager expose whether an animation is currently running?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [postponeEnterTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#postponeEnterTransition()) and the other associated operations to wait until the Cat is loaded?

Comment: I haven't used that before, but `Cat` is fragment A, and `Dog` is fragment B. The `Dog` being loaded is actually a part of the `Cat` fragment, because loading could fail (network error maybe?). Once the loading completes, the `CatFragment` crossfades back into its original state in parallel while `DogFragment` is being pushed onto the stack. I just want to delay the `CatFragment` from animating back to its original state while the `DogFragment`'s enter animation is being run. The issue is that internally, `CatFragment` runs its own animations, which conflicts w/ fragment transaction animations

Comment: This is a little confusing because `CatFragment`'s `LoadingABetterPet` state is not its initial state, but the last state the user should see before `DogFragment` is visible to the user.

`CatFragment` animates (animation 1) from it's loading state to its original state WHILE `DogFragment` is being animated by `.setCustomAnimations()` (animation 2). I want to delay animation 1 from executing until animation 2 completes. This way, animation 1 executes off screen.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest another solution. Personally I prefer loading data in the corresponding `Fragment`. I would suggest to move the loading to the `DogFragment` and change your workflow to

```
CatFragment.Cat --> (FragmentManager crossfade) 
--> DogFragment.Loading --> (crossfade) --> DogFragment.Dog
```

Comment: If loading fails, I need to go back to the `CatFragment`. In the future, I would hope that the loading screen isn't just a progress bar, but inline with the information in `CatFragment.Cat` state.

So this doesn't work.

Comment: In my solution, if the network call fails I would show the `DogFragment` with an error state and offer the retry possibility (if needed). Just because you do not like it does not mean that it does not work.

Comment: I see your point, but it's not something that makes sense for my actual flow. I'm not actually loading cats and dogs.

Comment: One more thing, you should really read about [voting down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). People spend time to help you, and voting down their efforts is not the right way to go.

Comment: You're right - I've been trying to vote you up but it's giving me an error